# Angular приложение не отправляет токен для аутентификации

Tags: angular, jwt

я использую следующий пакет для JWT: @auth0/angular-jwt
Для подключения использую следующий код:

```
HttpClientModule,
JwtModule.forRoot({
  config: {
    tokenGetter: () => localStorage.getItem(ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY),
    allowedDomains: ['localhost'],
  },
}),
```

Для отправки использую следующий:

```
public getAccounts(): Observable<AccountViewModel[]> {
return this.http.get<AccountViewModel[]>(`${this.apiUrl}/account/accounts`);}
```

Здесь видно что токен не отправлен:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У Вас в allowedDomains стоит 'localhost', а отправляете на 127.0.0.1:5000 попробуйте поменять на 127.0.0.1:5000

Comment: работает, спасибо